# How can I get the text style from window.selection()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, selection

I'm trying to get the css style of the text selection when user select **only 1 row**.

This is my code which works for **multiple lines selection** case:

```
var selectedDivs = window.selection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContent().children
// Then I can get css style from selectedDivs
```

But for **single line selection**, the `selectedDivs` is always `[]`. How can I get the css style in this case? I've tried startContainer & endContainer of range but it didn't work.

Comment: will jquery solution work for you?

Comment: @Alex: The above is a jQuery. haotang: There is no possible way to get the CSS style, unless you iterate through each property in CSS.. for each element you want. That means going through background, background-color, background-image, and so on.

Comment: @Snorlax: Yes. I've not found any topic about this. Actually I just wanna get the font-style & font-size of the selection / range. Still trying to search for the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentNode` of the `startContainer` should give you what you need.

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode
```